# Checkbox and foreach

Tags: php, mysql

I'm about to make a checkbox where it stores it I check
but I got a error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' Array, 5' at line 1`

I have Update my code now an i get a new ERROR:

"Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dashboard`.`das_custermers_employees`, CONSTRAINT `das_custermers_employees_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`das_employess_id`) REFERENCES `das_employer_roles` (`id`))"

Hope someone can help... i have put all my code in så hope someone can see what is wrong

My HTML

```
    <div class="contact_form_div">
            <form method="post">
                <?php
                global $wpdb;                        

if (isset($_POST['add_contact_btn'])) {

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM das_custermers_employees WHERE das_custermers_id = $user_custermers_id") or die(mysql_error());


    if (!empty($_POST['role_checkbox']) && is_array($_POST['role_checkbox'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['role_checkbox'] as $employess_roles) {
        foreach ($employess_roles as $em_id ){
            $employess_hidden = $_POST["employess_hidden_$em_id"];
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO das_custermers_employees(das_employess_id, employees_role_id, das_custermers_id) VALUES ($employess_hidden, $em_id, $user_custermers_id) ") or die(mysql_error());


        }
    }
    }
}
                        $show_employess = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM das_employess") or die(mysql_error());

                while ($my_employess = mysql_fetch_array($show_employess)) {

                    ?>                        
                        <b><? echo " " . $my_employess['first_name'] . " ";
                            echo $my_employess['last_name'] . " "; ?></b>
                        <?
                        $show_role = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM das_employer_roles") or die(mysql_error());

                        while ($my_role = mysql_fetch_array($show_role)) {

                            ?>
                            <input type="hidden" name="employess_hidden_<? echo $my_role['id']; ?>" value="<? echo $my_employess['id']; ?>" />
                            <em><p class="role_checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="role_checkbox[][<? echo $my_role['id']; ?>]" <? //if (mysql_num_rows($role_query) == 1) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="<? echo $my_role['id']; ?>"/><? echo " " . $my_role['role']; ?> </p></em>
                                <? } ?>                        
    <?
}

?>
                    <input value="Gem" name="add_contact_btn" type="submit" >
                    </form>
            </div>
```

Here is the table schema:
[image: Here is the database schema:]

Comment: could tell us where is the lines of code that generates an error?

Comment: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (dashboard.das_custermers_employees, CONSTRAINT das_custermers_employees_ibfk_5 FOREIGN KEY (das_employess_id) REFERENCES das_employer_roles (id))

Comment: if i echo my query out i can see the problem are in my hidden field but i cant se what is wrong :(

Comment: Did you see the fix to the hidden field in my answer?

Comment: you should post all the info out .

Comment: `role_checkbox[][<? echo $my_role['id']; ?>]` should be `role_checkbox[]` only

Comment: no beacuse there are many checkboxs in the while loop

Comment: checkboxes with same names as `[]` is consider as arrays. its worth to try.

Comment: It should probably be `role_checkbox[<? echo $my_role['id'] ?>][]`. The automatically created array needs to be last.

Comment: @ThomasGajhede can u post what should be the array format of `$_POST['role_checkbox']` results. Does it look like this `$_POST['role_checkbox'] = array('id'=>'role','id'=>'role');`

Comment: my checkbox look like Barmars answer :)

Comment: could you please post the whole code in your question (NOT in a comment -- click the edit button under the question)? I guess the code you posted under `My HTML` is inside the `$my_employess` loop? It's really confusing the way your code keeps switching between employee IDs and role IDs, I can't keep track of it.

Comment: I have to go to sleep, sorry.

Comment: i have do it now Barmar... all code is in

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing something.. check it below...

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO das_custermers_employees(das_employess_id, employees_role_id, das_custermers_id) VALUES ($employess_hidden, $em_id, $user_custermers_id)") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO das_custermers_employees(das_employess_id, employees_role_id, das_custermers_id) VALUES ($employess_hidden, $employess_roles, $user_custermers_id ") or die(mysql_error());
```

should be:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO das_custermers_employees(das_employess_id, employees_role_id, das_custermers_id) VALUES ($employess_hidden, $em_id, $user_custermers_id ") or die(mysql_error());
```

You were trying to interpolate the array into the `INSERT` statement, instead of the element from the `foreach` loop.

Also, change:

```
$employess_hidden = $_POST["employess_id_$em_id"];
```

to:

```
$employess_hidden = $_POST["employess_hidden_$em_id"];
```

There is no `employess_id_XXX` input in your form.

Comment: if i use that i get a error:
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 4, 5' at line 1"

Comment: Can you assign the query string in the `foreach` loop to a variable and var_dump it, and show that?

Comment: i think it in my HTML the problem is... the problem is it not get my das_employess_id :/ ...

Comment: here are the code there comes before my html.. maybe can it help
$show_employess = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM das_employess") or die(mysql_error());

                while ($my_employess = mysql_fetch_array($show_employess)) {
                    ?>
                       
                        
                        <b><? echo " " . $my_employess['first_name'] . " ";
                            echo $my_employess['last_name'] . " "; ?></b>

                        <?

Comment: $show_employess = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM das_employess") or die(mysql_error());

                while ($my_employess = mysql_fetch_array($show_employess)) {
                    ?>
                       
                        
                        <b><? echo " " . $my_employess['first_name'] . " ";
                            echo $my_employess['last_name'] . " "; ?></b>

                        <?

Comment: I don't think that matters. All that matters for the query with the error is `$employess_hidden`, `$em_id`, and `$user_custermers_id`.

Comment: See my updated answer. You were getting the wrong `$_POST` field.

Comment: Make sure you have error reporting enabled, so you get warnings about mistakes like that.

Comment: now it give a new error
"Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dashboard`.`das_custermers_employees`, CONSTRAINT `das_custermers_employees_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`das_employess_id`) REFERENCES `das_employer_roles` (`id`))"

Comment: That means you have to add the ID to the `das_employer_roles` before you can add a row containing it to `das_customers_employees`.

Comment: if i echo my querry out can i see at my hidden give me the wrong number but if i var_dump $my_employees can i se the id is right :/

Comment: What does `$my_employees` have to do with the code you posted? It's not being used in the INSERT statement.

Comment: $my_employees have the id to my employees and i need that in my many-to-many table das_custermers_employees

Comment: YOu need to add your table schema and more of the code to the question. It's hard to tell what your form is doing and how the database is organized.

Comment: Is this form used to add new employees, or add roles for old employees?

Comment: this checkbox can get(check) employess to my site